# Prove with epsilon delta the limit of $5x^3$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I try to prove the $\lim_{x \to a}5x^3$ with the epsilon-delta theorem for every real a.

I already came up with the idea of $0<|x-a|<\delta$

Since $|5x^3 - 5a^3| = 5|x-a||(x-a)^2 +3ax|$

Let $\delta<1$ and so $-1<x-a<1$

However, I don't know how to find out what $3ax$ is? Can someone please help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the identity $$
x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)
$$

you then have $$
|x^3 - a^3| < \epsilon
\\ \Leftarrow |x-a| (x^2 + |xa| + a^2) < \epsilon
\\ \Leftarrow |x-a| < \epsilon / R\ \ \  \& \ \ \  (x^2 + |xa| + a^2) < R
$$

Now you can prove that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $(x^2 + |xa| + a^2) $ is bounded by a certain $R(\delta)$.

Comment: But how can I simplify $x^2 + xa + a^2|?

Comment: What do you know about x^2, ax and a^2 if you use: -1<(x-a)<1

Comment: i made an edit.

Comment: let's say delta is smaller then 1, in that case: 
-1<x-a<1, so -1+a<x<1+a
However, substituting this in x^2, doesn't make it easier!

Comment: Yes it does. The upper bound you find does depend  only on $a$.

Comment: If I substitute $x<1+a$ and $x^2<(1+a)^2$ then you still keep |a| in the function.. 
What can I do with $3a^2+2a+1+|a| $ ?
Sorry, I worked a couple hours to solve this problem, but still didn't found out what epsilon should be..

Comment: Ohhh wait, in that case $|a|$ is always smaller or equal to a and this will give you $(x^2+|ax|+a^2) < 3a^2+3a+1$
In that case delta := min(1, epsilon/(3a^2+3a+1))???

Comment: yep, seems ok to me.